# Importing .json archives (Wordpress)

Tags: json, wordpress

I am currently developing a local version of a global website in Wordpress.

The archive of the global website has to be loaded into the local website and they have provided me with .JSON feeds instead of the usual .XML or .SQL dump.

I have been searching high and low on Google for some insight on how I can import the .JSON archives into Wordpress, but have been unable to find any article that is specific to this.

Hope someone here can provide a little insight how this can be done. Thanks guys =)